# Which Shadowrun book did this appear in?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

I remember a Shadowrun book released in the last 2-3 years that had a description of a "trid show" that focused on shadowrunners. It would follow actual shadowrunning teams on their runs, record stuff, then soon after release it on pay-per-view.

Which supplement did this appear in?

Comment: Sounds like someone's stealing from XCrawl!

Comment: The Sprawl Survival Guide from SR3 had this too.

Comment: There is this SR3 mission http://old.shadowrun4.com/missions/downloads/SRM00-04A_aforkinfatespath.pdf which put the runners is a situation like that

Answer (score 4):

There's a story like this in one of the glossy "fluff" sections of the Shadowrun 4E core rulebook, anniversary edition. I think maybe that's what you're thinking of?

Comment: I believe this example had someone stealing from a store. And it went on to say that there are "black trids" which have the main character dying in them.

Answer (score 4):

The story 'Fresh meat' in the 20th Anniversary edition* of the core rulebook by Jennifer Harding uses the conceit of a 'reality show' featuring a group of first time shadowrunners and documenting their story.

The short story itself only covers the team leader 'DangerSensei' (who is aware it is a reality show) meeting the potentials and choosing his team from them.

*it may also appear in base 4e, I can't confirm)